# Function to transform pandas column in percentage distribution

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have dataframe `df` and list `v_a`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A':[250,100,400,300,210]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

v_a = [0,200,400,600]
```

**Question:** I want to make a function that transform dataframe columns in `df` to percentage distribution.

**For example:** number 250 in `df` lies between 200 and 400 in `v_a`, then (400-250)/(400-200) = *0.75* is percentage it belongs to 200 and (1 - *0.75*) = *0.25* is percentage it belong 400.

Similarly, number 400 in `df` lies between 200 and 400 in `v_a` ( (400-400)/(400-200) = *0* for 400 in `v_a` and (1-*0*) = *1* for 200 in `v_a`).

**desired result**:

```
   0     200   400  600
0  0.0  0.75  0.25  0.0
1  0.5  0.50  0.00  0.0
2  0.0  0.00  1.00  0.0
3  0.0  0.50  0.50  0.0
4  0.0  0.95  0.05  0.0
```

Comment: I think desired result is wrong, you said : *0 for 400 in v_a*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution only with pandas:**

```
#Get DataFrame with intervals
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[interval.left, interval.right] 
                    for interval in pd.cut(df['A'], v_a)],
                   columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

---

```
#calculate values
df2['val2']=(df2['col2'].sub(df['A'])
                        .div(df2['col2'].sub(df2['col1']))
                        .clip(upper=1, lower=0))
df2['val1'] =  1 - df2['val2']

#print(df2)
#   col1  col2  val2  val1
#0   200   400  0.75  0.25
#1     0   200  0.50  0.50
#2   200   400  0.00  1.00
#3   200   400  0.50  0.50
#4   200   400  0.95  0.05
```

---

```
#Get the correct format
new_df = (pd.wide_to_long(df2.reset_index(),
                          ['col', 'val'],
                          i='index',
                          j='type') 
            .pivot_table(index='index',columns='col',values='val')
            .reindex(columns=v_a)
            .fillna(0)
            .rename_axis(columns=None, index=None))
```

**Output**

```
print(new_df)

#   0     200   400  600
#0  0.0  0.25  0.75  0.0
#1  0.5  0.50  0.00  0.0
#2  0.0  1.00  0.00  0.0
#3  0.0  0.50  0.50  0.0
#4  0.0  0.05  0.95  0.0
```

Comment: for another dataframe I am getting 'float' object has no attribute 'left'. For example: data = {'A':[1,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,2]},
v_a = [1,2,3,4]

Comment: I don't get any error with these data, but this is happening because when you use `pd.cut` there is some value that is NaN And this happens because that value is not within the limits of any interval, make sure to configure correctly v_a, or just use df2 = `df2=pd.DataFrame([[interval.left, interval.right] 
                    for interval in pd.cut(df['A'], v_a).dropna()],
                   columns=['col1', 'col2'])`

Comment: that is, having a NaN value instead of an interval tries to access the attribute `left` of the interval and since it does not exist it generates an error, so two solutions: reconfigure the interval or use `.dropna () `. Also you can use: `pd.cut(df['A'], v_a, include_lowest=True, precision=0).dropna()` 
because the problem is that the value 1 is not being included (the lowest), I suppose that this will change depending on the version of pandas and that's why I don't get an error for that case, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html